# VBA Regular Expression to match a time range like "1:30pm - 12:00am"

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to use a VBA regular expression to validate a time range of the form: `#0:00xm - #0:00xm` where `x` is `a` or `p`.  So the string literal could be `"1:30pm - 12:00am"`.  I want to match cells that have this pattern.

When I use the regular express in this online tool: `http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp` and check my expression, it matches correctly.

However, when I use the same expression in VBA, it does not match.

```
Dim rRange As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Set rRange = Range("A2", "A4") '"G225")

For Each rCell In rRange.Cells
MsgBox (rCell.Value)
    If rCell.Value Like "^([0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{2}[apm]{2}[ ][-][ ][0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{2}[apm]{2})$" Then
    MsgBox ("YES")
        'rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 250, 0)
    Else
    MsgBox ("NO")
        'rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 0, 0)
    End If
Next rCell
```

Comment: Check whether the LIKE operator is case-sensitive.  /[apm]{2}/ could be written as /[ap]m/, and it would be clearer what that acceptable strings are.

Comment: Now you're putting `/` in front of that.  Do you think that could be the problem?  If so, how would I correctly use the `/`?

Comment: @Matt don't use `/` - think of slashes as quotes around a `/regex literal/` (the syntax is actually used in perl, javascript and other languages)

Comment: +1 for deathApril's explanation.  If VBA's LIKE is the same as Visual Basic's LIKE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx), this operator doesn't take regular expressions at all.  So Scott's InStr() solution is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Matt - to use regex in VBA, see http://mark.biek.org/blog/2009/01/regular-expressions-in-vba/ - LIKE operator does not support regex pattern, but a wildcard pattern (http://www.oreilly.de/catalog/lrnwdpr/chapter/ch07_03.html#CH07-IDX-1000001875-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To anyone who cares, this is my fixed, working version with special thanks to dda for his simpler RegEx ^^:

```
Dim rRange As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Dim re As Object
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
  .Pattern = "^\d\d?:\d\d[aApP][mM] - \d\d?:\d\d[aApP][mM]$"
  .Global = False
  .IgnoreCase = False
End With

Set rRange = Range("A2", "G225")

For Each rCell In rRange.Cells
    If re.Test(rCell) Then
        rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 250, 0)
    Else
        rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 0, 0)
    End If
Next rCell
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's clean up and improve your regex:

```
^\d\d?:\d\d[aApP][mM] - \d\d?:\d\d[aApP][mM]$
```

This will only match if the whole cell is a date formatted like you want it, and nothing else (the ^***_*___**$ conditions).
I added both a and A, and p and P to be sure there's no case issues.

I don't have VBA/Excel on this machine, so can't try your code with my regex, but the regex per se works.

Comment: @Scott LIKE operator does not support RegEx, not VBA

Comment: ah...  so, is something like this considered RegEx - _($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* "-"_);_(@_) - . Beinga  self-taught VBA exploring other realms of programming, I am still learning a lot about programming outside of VBA! EDIT: -> nevermind, I see your link above

Comment: In which case use r.match: Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ; Dim m As Match = r.Match(text)

Comment: @Scott if you have a question not related to this answer, feel free to ask your own question..

Comment: @dda please edit your answer, not placing the most important info of an answer into comments

Comment: Shows that Matt at least was reading the comments ;-) Woop dee dah.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of Excel, go to Format Cells > Number > Category > Custom. You will see slew of time type formats.

What you are probably looking for is h:mm AM/PM

Okay. I did look more into this and realize my short-sightedness.

Is this more of what you are after? I did a basic test on a time value formatting with AM/PM and cells that are not formatted that way.

```
Dim rRange As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Set rRange = Range("A2", "A4")

For Each rCell In rRange
    If InStr(1, UCase(rCell.Value), " AM") > 0 Or InStr(1, UCase(rCell.Value), " PM") > 0 Then
        If InStr(1, rCell.Value, ":") <> 0 Then Debug.Print rCell.Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: i don't think you can regex-match a formatted number as it was a string - did you try it??

Comment: thanks for pointing my short-sightedness. I've edited my answer to a more functional VBA approach, I believe.